# I'm using WPF forms but when I add a new WindowsForm form, my program will run, but the windows form won't display

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF forms but when I add a new WindowsForm form, my program will run, but the windows form won't display. It says no error, but my program automatically stops debugging when i proceed to launch the windows form form. Can you help me? :'( I'm a student and I'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: Create a new WPF project in a new Visual Studio solution and try again. Do not try to add a WinForms form to a WPF project -- that's not beginner territory. If you really want to use WinForms, then create a WinForms project instead. Otherwise, any new project/solution should "just work" when you hit the debug button.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a Form in WPF app then you need to call `Show` function to show it.

```
Form1 form; // Your Form
form.Show();
```